# magento2 strigger is not working in javascript

Tags: magento2.3

In file main.phtml i have

```
<a href="<?=$block->getUrl("mpblog/post/history") . "?id=".$_post->getPostId()?>" class="edit-post"><span><?= __("Edit or delete post")?></span></a>
```

In file post.phtml i have

```
            foreach ($postCollection as $post) : ?>
                <div data-post-id="<?= $block->escapeHtml($post->getId()); ?>"
                     class="post-list-item col-mp post-item-list mp-12">
                    <div class="post-item-wraper">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getStatusHtmlById($post->getEnabled()) ?>
                        <?php if ($post->getImage()):
                            $images = explode("|",$post->getImage())?>
                            <div class="post-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo ($post->getEnabled() == 1) ? $post->getUrl() : 'javascript:void(0)' ?>">
                                    <img class="img-responsive"
                                         src="<?= $block->resizeImage($images[0], '400x'); ?>"
                                         alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml($post->getName()); ?>"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="post-info-wraper">
                            <h2 class="mp-post-title">
                                <a class="post-link-title" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($post->getName()); ?>"
                                   href="<?php echo ($post->getEnabled() == 1) ? $post->getUrl() : 'javascript:void(0)' ?>">
                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($post->getName()); ?>
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="mp-post-info">
                                <?= $block->getPostInfo($post); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-short-description">
                                <p><?= $block->maxShortDescription($post->getShortDescription()); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mp-clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="mp-post-meta-info mp-alignright">
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <a class="mp-read-more" href="<?php echo ($post->getEnabled() == 1) ? $post->getUrl() : 'javascript:void(0)' ?>"
                                       title="<?= __('Read More'); ?>">
                                        <?= __('Read More'); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-info-action" data-postId="<?= $block->escapeHtml($post->getId()); ?>">
                            <div class="mpblog-post-duplicate">
                                <img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_Blog::media/images/duplicate.svg') ?>"
                                     align="middle"
                                     alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Duplicate')); ?>"
                                     title="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                     __('Duplicate') ?>"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <?php $isDisableButton = $block->getDisableEditButton($post->getUpdatedAt());
                            if($isDisableButton):
                            ?>
                            <div class="mpblog-post-edit">
                                <img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_Blog::media/images/writing.svg') ?>"
                                     align="middle"
                                     alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Edit')); ?>"
                                     title="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                     __('Edit') ?>"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="mpblog-post-delete">
                                <img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl('Mageplaza_Blog::media/images/delete.svg') ?>"
                                     align="middle"
                                     alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete')) ?>"
                                     title="<?= /* @noEscape */
                                     __('Delete') ?>"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ($i++ % 2 == 0) : ?>
                    <div class="mp-clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <div class="mp-clear"></div>
        </div>
```

When i click in the  i will have js to trigger('click') to button edit

```
            var url_string = window.location.href;
            var url = new URL(url_string);
            var id = url.searchParams.get("id");

            
                $(function() {
                    $('body').ready(function() {
                        $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').trigger('click');
                    });
                });
```

But it not working. But if i use hide() it working. Only when i use trigger it not woriking. I don't know. Please help me

Comment: you use typeof operator check this link  --- https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists-or-defined-in-javascript.php and write , debug code following way.

Comment: i edited my question. but if i use hide() it working but when i use trigger() it not working. Please help me

Comment: you if condition add this type `if($('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').length > 0)` after try

Comment: i tried but it not working

Comment: i edit add code for you see

Comment: this div `<div class="mpblog-post-edit">` you call `onclick`  function

Comment: yes this is class i call

Comment: I try run 2 line:

$('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').trigger('click');

$('.post-list-item[data-post-id="24"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').hide();

But only hide() working

Comment: you try this `$('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').trigger('click'); $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="24"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

if($('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').length > 0){
    $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').trigger('click');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i edited my question. but if i use hide() it working but when i use trigger() it not working. Please help me

Comment: Try `$('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit')[0].click();` It would be helpfull if you add the html dom hierarchy showing the elements in your question for reference.

Comment: i tried but it not working

Comment: Please add your html code in your question to have better idea, also see if there is any console error.

Comment: i added for you see

Comment: Are you sure that click event is written for ".mpblog-post-edit" and not for ".mpblog-post-edit img" ?? Do you have that JS event code ?

Comment: Yes i sure i write for .moblog-post-edit. But when i use hide() it working, trigger() it not working. I tried ".mpblog-post-edit img" but also not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

if(typeof id !== 'undefined' && $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').length > 0){
    $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: i edited my question. but if i use hide() it working but when i use trigger() it not working. Please help me

Comment: Why do you not use a simple click(); ? like this :     $('.post-list-item[data-post-id="'+id+'"]').find('.mpblog-post-edit').click();

Comment: i tried but it not working also

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no don't have error

Comment: i add code for you see..